# How to return object from custom adapter in listview using setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I *know* there are many variations of this question already...I've read them. But no solutions yet so here goes.

- I have a local database which stores dates, times etc of event
  objects.
- The database has a method that returns an Arraylist of all event objects.
- I have a custom adapter linked to a listview, that uses the arrayList of Events from the database and uses 'get' methods on each object to display a scrolling schedule of all events.

so far, so good.

Now, I want to be able to click an item in the listview and delete it using setOnItemClickListener. The database has a 'deleteEvent' method which takes an 'id' of the event to be deleted. The 'id' can be gained through a 'getEventId' method in the EventObject class.

So, I need a way to get a reference to the relevant EventObject when an item in the listview is clicked, so that I can call 'getId' and remove that event from the database.

```
eventsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //EventObject e1 = ???
            dbHandler.deleteEvent(e1.getEventId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `EventObject e1=list.get(position)`.. Where `list` is the dataset which you are using to populate listview . Make sure to notify `Listview` after Deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by ADM:

`EventObject e1=list.get(position)`

Where `list` is the dataset (arrayList) which you are using to populate `listview` . Make sure to notify Listview (refresh activity) after Deletion.